# Detecting when beacon is IN/OUT of range is called multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I have a viewController that detects if a beacon is in range or out of range and send a local notification and save some data in the database

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    .
    .
    .
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || status == .AuthorizedAlways{
        if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLBeaconRegion.self) {
            if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                startScanning()
            }
        }
    }
}

func startScanning() {

    for var i=0; i<deviceObjectArray.count; i++ {
        let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: deviceObjectArray[i].uuid)!
        let major = UInt16(deviceObjectArray[i].major)
        let minor = UInt16(deviceObjectArray[i].minor)
        beaconRegionsArray.append(CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: major!, minor: minor!, identifier: deviceObjectArray[i].deviceName))
    }
    for var i=0; i<beaconRegionsArray.count; i++ {
        locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegionsArray[i])

    }
}
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Entering region")
    myTitle = "Entering the range"
    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: "Press OK to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertBody1 = "Entering beacon range"
    LocalNotification()


}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    print("Exiting region")
    myTitle = "Exiting the range"
    var alertView = UIAlertController(title: myTitle, message: "Press OK to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: yesHandler))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alertBody1 = "Exiting beacon range"
    LocalNotification()
    setMyLocation(region.identifier)
}
```

More or less the code works. When the beacon is out of range, I get a local notification and data get saved to database when

setMyLocation(region.identifier) gets call.

However  the problem I have is if I leave this view and come back to it again, next time the function

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
```

gets call a few times and suddenly I get like 10 or 15 messages

"Exiting beacon range"

and also the same data get saved 10 or 15 times.
How can I fix this problem?

Should I create a class by itself and isolate this from the ViewController?

Not sure if I am clear enough but any help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious why you get extra exit events, but it may be because you are trying to register more than the 20 allowed monitoring regions.  Perhaps you get exit events when the older regions are unloaded by CoreLocation when you go over the limit.

The issue with going over the limit happens because you call `startMonitoringForRegion` when the ViewController loads, but never call `stopMonitoringFirRegion` on each region when the ViewController becomes inactive.

I would change this and maybe it will fix your problem.  Just a guess -- if that does not work it may be time to decouple the beacon code from your ViewController as you suggest.

Comment: thanks for the info. In my application I will 4  or 5 view controllers which I can move back and forth between them. I also want  to be able to get notification if I am within a registered beacon range regardless of which viewcontroller I am currently in. what is the best way to design such an app? Should all my viewcontroller classes have CLLocationManagerDelegate in it?

Comment: It is typical for apps to centralize beacon detection code in the AppDelegate.